# How to compute 2D density maps in GROMACS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs

I have a GROMACS trajectory of MD simulation. I want to make a contour plot of density as a function of two coordinates, namely X and Z. Is it possible to get this using `gmx density`? If not, is there any other way?

Answer (score 4):

[gmx density](https://manual.gromacs.org/current/onlinehelp/gmx-density.html) can help in finding partial densities either along a particular axis (generally z axis) or with respect to the center of the box. It does not make a contour plot. However, [gmx densmap](https://manual.gromacs.org/current/onlinehelp/gmx-densmap.html) can be used for computing 2D density maps. Both the commands need trajectory file as input files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can use gmx-densmap and set the average along the y-axis to get the contour plot showing the density as a function of the x and z-axis and the average over the y-axis.

Use the command as :

gmx densmap -f trj.trr -s trj.tpr -o densmap.xpm -aver y -n index.ndx -bin 0.01

Use index.ndx to calculate the density of a selected atom or molecule.